# How can I define the size of the ElasticSearch aggregations response, using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST to write an aggregation query which should result in all possible values for a certain field.

The json variant of what I wish to implement:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user-name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 1000    <== 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the AggregationContainerDescriptor I currently have:

```
var descriptor = new AggregationContainerDescriptor<User>();
descriptor.Terms("user-name", x => x.Field("username"))
```

This would return by default 10 results. How can set the response size to 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var descriptor = new AggregationContainerDescriptor<User>();
descriptor.Terms("user-name", x => x.Size(1000).Field("username"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: It's a straight question with a straight answer. The same way there is no additional context in answering "what is 2+2?". At least this is the way I see it. If you can improve this answer I'm open to any edit requests :)